# InceptionV4 and V2 giving low accuracy on "flower dataset" than InceptionV1

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tf-slim

I am using the following code to train flower dataset on InceptionV1. This code is provided [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/slim_walkthrough.ipynb)

```
import os

from datasets import flowers
from nets import inception
from preprocessing import inception_preprocessing

slim = tf.contrib.slim
image_size = inception.inception_v1.default_image_size


def get_init_fn():
    """Returns a function run by the chief worker to warm-start the training."""
    checkpoint_exclude_scopes=["InceptionV1/Logits", "InceptionV1/AuxLogits"]

exclusions = [scope.strip() for scope in checkpoint_exclude_scopes]

variables_to_restore = []
for var in slim.get_model_variables():
    excluded = False
    for exclusion in exclusions:
        if var.op.name.startswith(exclusion):
            excluded = True
            break
    if not excluded:
        variables_to_restore.append(var)

return slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
  os.path.join(checkpoints_dir, 'inception_v1.ckpt'),
  variables_to_restore)


train_dir = '/tmp/inception_finetuned/'

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

dataset = flowers.get_split('train', flowers_data_dir)
images, _, labels = load_batch(dataset, height=image_size, width=image_size)

# Create the model, use the default arg scope to configure the batch norm parameters.
with slim.arg_scope(inception.inception_v1_arg_scope()):
    logits, _ = inception.inception_v1(images, num_classes=dataset.num_classes, is_training=True)

# Specify the loss function:
one_hot_labels = slim.one_hot_encoding(labels, dataset.num_classes)
slim.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(logits, one_hot_labels)
total_loss = slim.losses.get_total_loss()

# Create some summaries to visualize the training process:
tf.scalar_summary('losses/Total Loss', total_loss)

# Specify the optimizer and create the train op:
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train_op = slim.learning.create_train_op(total_loss, optimizer)

# Run the training:
final_loss = slim.learning.train(
    train_op,
    logdir=train_dir,
    init_fn=get_init_fn(),
    number_of_steps=2)



print('Finished training. Last batch loss %f' % final_loss)
```

I Evaluated the model using following code and got accuracy of 58.34%

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from datasets import flowers
from nets import inception

slim = tf.contrib.slim

image_size = inception.inception_v1.default_image_size
batch_size = 3

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

    dataset = flowers.get_split('train', flowers_data_dir)
    images, images_raw, labels = load_batch(dataset, height=image_size, width=image_size)

# Create the model, use the default arg scope to configure the batch norm parameters.
with slim.arg_scope(inception.inception_v1_arg_scope()):
    logits, _ = inception.inception_v1(images, num_classes=dataset.num_classes, is_training=True)
    predictions = tf.argmax(logits, 1)


checkpoint_path = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(train_dir)
init_fn = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
  checkpoint_path,
  slim.get_variables_to_restore())

names_to_values, names_to_updates = slim.metrics.aggregate_metric_map({
    'eval/Accuracy': slim.metrics.streaming_accuracy(predictions, labels),
    'eval/Recall@5': slim.metrics.streaming_recall_at_k(logits, labels, 5),
})

# Define the streaming summaries to write:
for metric_name, metric_value in names_to_values.items():
    tf.summary.scalar(metric_name, metric_value)

print('Running evaluation Loop...')
# Load the most recent checkpoint of variables saved
checkpoint_path = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(train_dir)
# Evaluates the model at the given checkpoint path
metric_values = slim.evaluation.evaluate_once(
    master='',
    checkpoint_path=checkpoint_path,
    logdir=train_dir,
    num_evals=100,
    eval_op=list(names_to_updates.values()),
    final_op=list(names_to_values.values()),
    summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all())

names_to_values = dict(zip(names_to_values.keys(), metric_values))
for name in names_to_values:
    print('%s: %f' % (name, names_to_values[name]))
```

Apart from configuring checkpoints and training directories, I only replaced "V1" in the code with "V2" and "V4" and trained the model.

Firstly the training loss is throughout constant for both "V2" and "V4" around 4% for all 100 iterations. 
Secondly, evaluation accuracy comes around 25% for both "V2" and "V4"

I'm new to TF so there's definitely something I am missing here, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I once did a transfer learning with pretrained inception V3 on the flower photos dataset and can reach peak accuracy about 94%, why your accuracy is much lower than mine?

Comment: @Jie.Zhou Can you please share your code? I'm exactly not sure why is that happening, I must be missing something

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that may go wrong when fine-tuning a fairly large convolutional network like Inception V3. Here are some pointers you could look into to improve your model:

- The training code you've posted above excludes the `InceptionV1/Logits` and `InceptionV1/AuxLogits` from being loaded into the `tf.Graph`. These tensors are the fully connected layers on top of a convolutional base. In essence, this allows you to train your own `InceptionV1/Logits` and `InceptionV1/AuxLogits`. This code, however, does not "freeze" the convolutional base, meaning the convolutional filters are trainable. This is a bad idea because large gradients flowing from randomly initialized fully connected layers may wreck the learned weights in the convolutional base. This has a more catastrophic effect on larger networks, which may explain why V2 and V4 did worse than V1. You can read more about fine-tuning networks [here](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html).
- The learning rate of 0.01 seems exceptionally high for fine-tuning the network. Usually, pre-trained models would have learned the lower-level filters such as lines and edges detection so you wouldn't want to alter their weights much. A learning rate of <=0.001 will suffice.
- However from what you've described, the model does not seem to converge because it is stuck at 0.04 for 100 iterations, which would suggest to increase the learning rate. I am still unsure about this. Perhaps the code is just an example and is not supposed to be adapted to other models.

Tensorflow has a more documented section on fine-tuning different models [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception#how-to-fine-tune-a-pre-trained-model-on-a-new-task). It also uses `slim` which is a more user-friendly and terse wrapper of Tensorflow. Perhaps you can give that a try. Good luck.